# How to calculate duration of event at different speeds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

Specifically I want to figure out the formula which will tell me: how long will it take to watch this video (normal length $L$) at speed $x$.

I think this will be asymptotic, no matter how fast you play a video, it will take *some* time, even as that dwindles down towards $0$, it will never hit.  I also assume that playing a video at speed $x=2$ would mean $\text{duration} = \frac{L}{2}$, but I'm unclear how to translate that into a general equation.  For instance, when $x=1.4$.

A brief explanation of the method of calculating this would be best.

Comment: It's just $L/x$. This is analogous to "rate $\times$ time = distance" so "time = distance/rate".

Comment: It pretty much boils down to the definition of "speed". I'm assumng that "normal length" corresponds to speed $x=1$. By a speed of $x=k$, presumably you mean that something that took $k$ seconds before now only takes $1$ second. This should allow you to work out your formula easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The playback rate is the number of seconds of video per second of real time, i.e. $R = V/T$. Rearranging that, you get $T = V/R$, i.e. the amount of real time is equal to the length of video divided by the rate. So a 4 minute video at 1.5 rate takes $4/1.5=2.67$ minutes, or 2 minutes 40 seconds.

Comment: Now I see it, I'm kicking myself for how obvious!  Been years since I've done any real math, thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

The basic relation is
$$
s = v t
$$
where e.g. $v$ is tape speed and $s$ is tape length.

If you go from $v$ to $v' = x v$ the length $s$ stays the same, but the time has to change to $t'$:
$$
s = v t = v' t' = x v t'
$$
so
$$
t' = v t / (x v) = t / x
$$
So if you double the speed by $x=2$, you half the viewing time to $t' = t/2$.
In general this is
$$
t' = t / x
$$

Comment: I assume the same thing can be applied to objects moving over distance (car traveling at 2x speeds travels distance in 1/2 the time) also?

Comment: Yes, the physical origin is $v = ds/dt$. If this rate of change in time $v$ is constant, and you start with $s=0$ at $t=0$ you end up with $s = v t$.  Such relationships hold for other quantiies as well not just distance.